# Qual a diferença entre expressão de função e definição de função em relação a hoisting no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções, sintaxe, ecmascript-5

Qual a diferença entre expressão de função (nomeada ou não nomeada) e definição de função em relação a hoisting no *JavaScript*?

Sintaxe expressão de função nomeada:

```
var somar = function somar(a, b) {
   return a + b;
};
```

Sintaxe expressão de função, mais conhecida como função anônima:

```
var somar = function(a, b) {
   return a + b;
};
```

Sintaxe definição de função:

```
function somar(a, b) {
   return a + b;
}
```

E onde é mais recomendado a utilização de cada uma delas?